# Programmatically navigate a graph in Gephi

Tags: gephi

Gephi's scripting plugin allows us to interact with a graph in a variety of manners, but it lacks any features for manipulating the graph viewer, i.e., the interface used to visually navigate a graph. What options do I have if I want to, e.g., set a particular zoom level, or center the view around a particular node, and do so programmatically?